# Red highlight in Material shading mode?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]So, when I go into the Material shading mode in Cycles, everything seems to have this strange red light shining on it from below (relative to the view, of course). Does anybody have an idea as to why this is? [EDIT added photo.]

Comment: In my [default scene](https://imgur.com/a/09Br4ax) with cycles, there isn't any colored light. Add additional info/screenshot. It may be a material, texture, light, world illumination, matcap or OpenGL setting which changes the color.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't some red light in your scene? (Alt H to unhide everything on the current layer.)

Comment: Positive. It happens in practically every scene I have. I even appended some models into a completely fresh file and it still appeared. I removed the HDRi, everything I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your prefs in the systems tab. This is just the default viewport lighting. You can change it. It does not effect your renderings.